# How to get the children of a string according to the dot

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, linq, informix

I have code numbers as the following sequential:

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
.
.
.
1.1.1
1.1.2
.
.
.
2
```

And so..

I want a method to that parses the children based on some input. For example, if the input is `1` then it will retrieve all it's children, and if the input is `1.1` it will retrieve all of it's children, etc.

How can I do something like that?

**Notes:**

- This data is stored in one table in `Informix` database.
- The code numbers are strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code

```
var list = new List<string>();
var children = list.Where(s => s.StartsWith(inputString));
```

DB

```
DECLARE @p1 varchar(100)
SET @p1 = '1.1%'
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE tbl.col LIKE @p1
```

Comment: Code is supposed to be self explanatory.

Comment: ok that's good but what about the database:

 
i wanna some thing general ,if i wanna the childs of `1`, or `1.1.1`

you talk specially about `1.1`!

Comment: Just set the `@p1` variable to whatever you are looking for, `'1%'` or `'1.1.1%'`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable
WHERE codestring LIKE '1.1%';
```

should do the trick.

Comment: i wanna some thing general ,if i wanna the childs of `1`, or `1.1.1`?

Comment: Then insert whatever parent string you're looking for in place of the `1.1`. But if you're going to need more complex queries, you'd probably be better off redoing this table as a parent/child relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Will not a simple sql query solve it??

something like

```
SELECT * from the_table where column matches "input*"?
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be different - using SUBSTR etc instead of LIKE:

```
SELECT *
  FROM AnonymousTable
 WHERE SUBSTR(CodeNumbers, 1, LENGTH(<xxx>)) = <xxx>;
```

Where the `<xxx>` notation indicates where you place the argument.  There are various notations for that, depending on exactly how the SQL is being handled.  The one downside is that it requires two references to the same parameter value.